# CruiseControl.NET double building nant file

Tags: c#, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I've just started using ccnet and it appears to be double building the nant file: The build log shows the build output twice:

> Buildfile: file:///D:/ccnet/path/go.build Target framework: Microsoft
>   .NET Framework 2.0 Target(s) specified: test

.. etc..

> Buildfile: file:///D:/ccnet/path/go.build Target framework: Microsoft
>   .NET Framework 2.0 Target(s) specified: test

But I only have one nant task in my ccnet.config. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If nant is putting output to the standard out it is getting wrapped upinto the build log automatically, then if you have Nant create an results file and you merge that in, you will get double results. I have seen it happen so this may be your issue. If it is, the best way to fix it is to get rid of the merge step and just let CC.NET consume the stdOut

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I found this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ccnet-user/iQvRWL7fX4Y

> When i Click on forcebuild button for particular project through 
>   webdashboard. that project is running two times instead of one.
>
> **> I've seen similar behaviour when hitting the Force button followed by 
>   a browser refresh/F5, I assume it results in the request being sent to
>   the server twice...using the "Refresh status" button on the site 
>   itself seemed to stop it for me.**

So after reading the above......I tried something else:
When I went through CCTray, I did not have the issue.

I am currently testing.  But I'm pretty sure you cannot click the "Refresh Status" button on the cc.net dashboard webpage (which is the EXACT thing you want to do as you monitor the progress of the build)

Comment: So yeah.  If I clicked on "Force Rebuild" and didn't touch the "Refresh Status", only one build was kicked off.  Good to know since the build takes about 15 minutes and consumes about 30MB of space !